# Message Icon enum

Tags: java

While using a `JOptionPane`, recently, it struck me as odd that the Java Library doesn't seem to have any standard icons for the dialogs.  So I decided to create an enum for them.  Instead of mapping the icons directly to the enum, I used a map.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Map;

public enum MessageIcons {
    PLAIN(-1),
    ERROR(0),
    INFORMATION(1),
    WARNiNG(2),
    QUESTION(3);
    private Icon value;
    private final Map<Integer, Icon> icons = Map.of(
            -1,new ImageIcon("Plain.png"),
            0,new ImageIcon("Error.png"),
            1,new ImageIcon("Information.png"),
            2,new ImageIcon("Warning.png"),
            3,new ImageIcon("Question.png")
    );
    MessageIcons(int value){
        this.value = icons.get(value);
    }
    public Icon getIcon(){
        return value;
    }
}
```

Images:
[image: Plain.png]  [image: Error.png]  [image: Information.png]  [image: Warning.png]     [image: Question.png]

I've mapped these to the same values as those in the `JOptionsPane`.

Comment: Please do not update the code in the question to invalidate answers.

Comment: Not wrong, but it might be a good idea to have some kind of configuration instead so designers can quickly test different icons without having to rename / change the source. Depends a bit on the project of course; for a one-off tool this would not be necessary.

Answer (score 6):

In my opinion, binding the file to the enum is a better choice. This will make the code shorter and give the same performance. Also, the `MessageIcons#WARNiNG` have a lowercase in the name (`MessageIcons#WARNiNG` -> `MessageIcons#WARNING`).

```java
public enum MessageIcons {
    PLAIN("Plain.png"),
    ERROR("Error.png"),
    INFORMATION("Information.png"),
    WARNING("Warning.png"),
    QUESTION("Question.png");
    private final Icon icon;

    MessageIcons(String fileName) {
        icon = new ImageIcon(fileName);
    }

    public Icon getIcon() {
        return icon;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the use of `code`? It is final and private and not used? Also `value` is not a great name for an `icon` ;)

Comment: For the `value` variable, I kept the original name, but you're right, it's a bad name. I will rename it to `icon`. For the `code` variable, there's no use in this case :P. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For me it is a bit weird to see an enum representing a resource, even if it is in memory. It's not wrong or anything, but currently even the loading takes place during construction of the enum. Furthermore, as mentioned in a comment, I can see where another icon needs to be tested / substituted. In that case it might make sense to update the file name for a specific configuration.

That aside, I would do more of a code review rather than giving a good solution, because that's been taken care of.

First of all, I'd put empty lines around the `value` field declaration and in between the methods and constructors. That would improve readability by a lot.

---

```
public enum MessageIcons {
```

I would not use plural `MessageIcons` but just `MessageIcon`. That way you get `MessageIcon.PLAIN` which reads better than `MessageIcons.PLAIN`. I hope you agree, because this is how it is used everywhere that I've seen.

```
PLAIN(-1),
```

Maybe it's a leftover from before, but it seem strange that you start counting with `-1`. Generally we don't number enums at all; it is just not required. And otherwise you can simply call the `ordinal()` method on the enum value. But before you do, read up on the documentation of it (!).

```
private final Map<Integer, Icon> icons = Map.of(...);
```

If you would create a map for enums then there is absolutely no need to use an `Integer`. It is much more simple to directly use enum values themselves, giving you a `Map<MessageIcons, Icon>`.

Remember that each enum is really a singleton. What you are doing here is to create 5 separate maps, one for `PLAIN`, one for `ERROR`, etc.! If you create a map (which is one option to create a two way table for a value -> enum on top of enum -> value) then it should be `static`.

```
-1,new ImageIcon("Plain.png"),
```

There should be a space after the comma. That's common code style as well.

```
MessageIcons(int value){
```

Generally the constructor of an enum is only used for the enumerated enum values. So generally you should make it `private`. This and the next method `getIcon` also do not have a space between the closing parenthesis and the brace. That's almost universal for Java and other C-like languages.